# implementing bulkEditGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm a newbie so please.. be kind.

I'm trying to implement the bulkEditGridView via Microsoft visual studio express 2013. with no success.
I've copied the DLL found here: http://aspnetrealworldcontr.codeplex.com/releases/view/1674 to my bin directory, and then imported it to the toolbox (right click > choose items).

But some why it gives me this error:

> Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field
>   'BulkEditGridView1', but its type (RealWorld.Grids.BulkEditGridView)
>   is not compatible with the type of control (RealWorld.Grids

Please help. Thank you
This is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="RealWorld.Grids" Namespace="RealWorld.Grids" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">   
        <cc1:BulkEditGridView ID="BulkEditGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" EnableInsert="False" InsertRowCount="1" SaveButtonID="">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="hall" HeaderText="hall" SortExpression="hall" />
            </Columns>
        </cc1:BulkEditGridView>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:syngTimeConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [T_Hall]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, probably something went wrong with my project. (maybe web.config or something else). I've opened a new clean project. and It works.